# Partial match on key composed of two columns

Tags: sql

Let s say my two tables keys  are comprised of column A and B:

Table 1

```
Column A Column B
1                1
1                X
2                2
3                3
```

Table 2

```
Column A Column B
1                1
2                2
3                3
```

How do I select only the rows in Table1 where the key only matches partially.   My intended result would pulling out row:

```
Column A Column B
1               X
```

Basically finding all rows where Column A and B match but where following records were ´left out' in Table 2

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from tabl1
join tabl2
on (tabl1.cola == tabl1.cola and tabl1.colb <> tabl1.colb)
or (tabl1.cola <> tabl1.cola and tabl1.colb == tabl1.colb)
```

Answer (score 0):

join the tables on "partial" match

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on ((t1.a = t2.a and t1.b <> t2.b) or (t1.a <> t2.a and t1.b = t2.b))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using NOT-EXISTS subquery:

```
SELECT
  input1.ColumnA,input1.ColumnB
FROM
  t1
WHERE
  NOT EXIST (
    SELECT *
    FROM t2
    WHERE t1.ColumnB = t2.ColumnB AND t1.ColumnA = t2.ColumnA)
```

Explanation: you select rows in table1 whose values are not contained in table2.